# JavaScript cookie not saving

Tags: javascript

I am having a trouble with JavaScript cookie. I run this code last time and it worked like what I want to. It shows a prompt letting me to enter my name, and clicks OK after entering my name. It also worked when I refreshed the page and shows an alert message saying " Welcome again Mark". 
    But now, this code does not work anymore. It only ask and ask my name everytime I refresh the page. I'm doubting if it's on my browser I already tries tor un this code in IE, Firefox, Chrome, and MS Edge but it does the same thing. Hope you cans olve the problem guys. Thanks. The code is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays)
      {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
      }
      function getCookie(cname)
      {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++)
        {
          var c = ca[i];
          while(c.charAt(0) == ' ')
          {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if(c.indexOf(name) == 0)
          {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
          }
        }
        return "";
      }
      function checkCookie()
      {
        var username = getCookie("username");
        if(username != null && username != "")
        {
          alert("Welcome again " + username);
        } else
        {
          username = prompt("Please enter your name:" , "");
          if(username != null && username != "")
          {
            setCookie("username" , username , 365);
          }
        }
      }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="checkCookie()">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not quietly understand it. You mean if Console works properly in my browser?

Comment: I meant if there was any errors showing up in the console when you open the page. Also, in your code why do you define a variable `d` in `setCookie` if you don't use it afterwards? Is it meant to be used for `expires` ?

Comment: Actually it's:  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();

Answer (score 3):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 
1000));
var expires = "expires=";
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + 
expires;
```

Your cookie string doesn't include the date. You forgot the `+ d`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to include ...d.toGMTString()

Comment: Just saw my own question after some years. I wanna thank you for answering even though I asked a very st*pid question <3

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably this line:

```
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " +
            expires;
```

You forgot adding the date:

```
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " +
            expires + d;
```

Comment: Oh and of course:
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ", " + 
expires + d;

Comment: Another thing is... If I run the code in Chrome, I will only get a prompt box asking for my name, and in Firefox, giving me an alert box saying "Welcome again Mark"

Comment: When you are testing this, are you opening a file, or running this on a locally hosted webserver? AFAIK, running as a file doesn't allow saving cookies.

Comment: I only go to the location of the file, and opens it. I don't open any web server.

Comment: Just saw my own question after some years. I wanna thank you for answering even though I asked a very st*pid question <3